# Show that $\left\{ (x,t) \in X \times \mathbb{R} \colon 0 \leq t \leq u(x) \right\} \in \mathscr{A} \otimes \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathscr{A}, \mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $u \in 
\mathscr{M}^+ (\mathscr{A})$. Let
$$G_u = \left\{ (x,t) \in X \times \mathbb{R} \colon 0 \leq t \leq u(x) \right\}.$$
Show that $G_u \in \mathscr{A} \otimes \mathscr{B} (\mathbb{R})$.

I've been given a hint to use the Sombrero Lemma, but can't get it to work. Could anyone help and maybe tell me whether the following is wrong?:

Let $v (x,t) = u(x)$ and $s(x,t)=t$. Then
$$ \left\{ v\geq a \right\} = \left\{ u\geq a\right\} \times \mathbb{R} \in \mathscr{A}
\times \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$$
$$ \left\{ s\geq a\right\} = X \times \left\{t\geq a\right\} \in \mathscr{A} \times 
\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}).$$
So $v,s$ are measurable, and thus
\begin{align*}
    \left\{ u(x)\geq t \geq 0 \right\}
    &= \left\{ v(x,t) \geq s(x,t) \geq 0\right\}\\
    &= \left\{ v(x,t) \geq s(x,t) \right\} \cap
       \left\{ s(x,t) \geq 0 \right\} \in \mathscr{A} \otimes \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})
\end{align*}

Comment: You can start with simple functions. Then by approximating nonnegative  functions by simple functions monotonically.

Comment: You asked this question twice; here and [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4573505/121671). I suggest that you remove one. Question should be posted only once. Edits are allowed in case improvements are needed.